# An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow - how "handle" getting a null record?

Tags: visual-workflow, error-messages, screen-flow, null, unhandled-exception

I have a screen flow where the user selects a pair of records.
The flow attempts to get a related record that may or may not exist, then branches based on null/not null.

The relevant Get Records element uses "Choose fields and assign variables (advanced)" with "When no records are returned, set specified variables to null" enabled.

The Flow now works in my sandbox, but in the main org it still throws an ["unhandled" fault](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179530/how-to-debug-flow-errors) because of missing field values (if getPE returns null). I added a fault handler but it has no effect. Also, it's not a [Required field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155334/error-using-flows-required-field-missing).

[image: Flow Builder screenshot]

Here is the Debug output:

```
GET RECORDS: getPE Find all PE__c records where: 
AoE__c Equals {!myAoE.recordId} (...) AND 
Program__c Equals {!getSP.Program__r.Id} (...) 
Store those records in {!myPE}. 
Save these field values in the variable: Id, LO__c 
Result
Failed to find records. 
Error element Choose_SE (FlowScreen). 
The flow failed to access the value for myPE.Id 
because it hasn't been set or assigned.
```

Why is it claiming there's an error back in the original flow screen, when the screen doesn't reference the missing record at all?

Why is it working in one org but not the other? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show the specific flow element detail for the element that errors please, and include the full error message. Debugging the flow will help get the detail as to exactly where the error happens.

Comment: are you querying the related record even if the lookup Id value is NULL?

Comment: @PhilW screenshots & debugger messages added.

Comment: @cropredy it's a single Get Record element. I have to look for the record to find out if it exists or not, right?

Comment: Your screen element must be referencing a field in a null record. You have to check that the record variable is not null before referencing any fields in that record variable

Comment: I know this may seem obvious, but have you confirmed that the latest version of your flow has been activated? Given it now works in a sandbox it sounds like your fix has worked and now there's something not right with the version in production. Have you compared the metadata of the active versions in prod vs non-prod?

Comment: If the flow is working in sandbox and latest version on prod is activated another idea is to completely remove the flow and recreate/redeploy it again (preferably with different api name). Once we had similar issues as you and apparently something was completely broken on the platform.

Comment: - If it worked in the sandbox, but not in production, then it's possible you didn't activate the latest version of the flow in the sandbox before deploying. When deploying a flow from the sandbox, the active version -- not the most recent version -- gets deployed. You might already know this, but can you check and make sure that you deployed the correct version of your flow? - If that's not it, can you share the full details of the getPE element configuration, and the full debug log?

Comment: @AdamVatterott Adam, thanks for the suggestions.
I have verified the flow in prod is up to date and matches sandbox.
getPE is a Get Records element where AoE = getAOE > ID and Prog = getSP > Prog > ID. Store only the first, assign variables, when no records: set to null.  Standard stuff, nothing complicated.
I found a workaround in prod by storing the field results in separate values rather than a record variable. Still no idea why there's a difference between orgs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no other admins making changes, the only thing that could be different without your knowledge between a sandbox and production would be a Salesforce Release preview. If it is that, or a bug, Salesforce Support should be able to support you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this later -- I've dealt with this before in the past, although it's extremely rare.

I found that by using a **separate text variable**, then "Choose fields and assign variables (advanced)" with "When no records are returned, set specified variables to null" and **assigning the Id to that text variable** circumvented the issue.

I have no idea why this worked.